# '_Wherenode was nullptr' when adding to static std::map

Tags: c++, initialization, linkage, factory-method

I've been following [this tutorial / example](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/02/factory-selfregister.html) on creating a self-registering type in C++17. But I've run into a problem: Upon a type's attempt to register, my program terminates with the error `read access violation. _Wherenode was nullptr.` This error occurs in the standard library's `std::_Tree<std::Tmap_traits<...>::_Lbound` method.

This is my source code, nearly identical to that on the page (with some tweaks to fix errors the original code had:)

```
class Entity { ... }; // Contents irrelevant

class EntityTypeFactory {
public:
    using TCreateMethod = std::function<Entity* ()>;

    EntityTypeFactory() = delete;

    static Entity* Create(const std::string& type);

    static bool Register(const std::string& name, TCreateMethod func);

private:
    static std::map<std::string, TCreateMethod> s_methods;
};

#define REG_ENT(TYPE) class TYPE##Creator { private: static bool s_created; }; \
bool TYPE##Creator::s_created = EntityTypeFactory::Register(#TYPE, []() -> Entity* { return new TYPE(); });


std::map<std::string, EntityTypeFactory::TCreateMethod>* EntityTypeFactory::s_methods;

Entity* EntityTypeFactory::Create(const std::string& type)
{
    if (s_methods == nullptr) return nullptr;

    return (*s_methods)[type]();
}

bool EntityTypeFactory::Register(const std::string& name, TCreateMethod func)
{
    if (s_methods == nullptr)
        s_methods = new std::map<std::string, TCreateMethod>();

    (*s_methods)[name] = func;
    return true;
}

class Foo : public Entity {}; // Contents irrelevant

REG_ENT(Foo)
```

**Edit:** This seems to have to do with the linking order, as if I place my test implementation `Foo` in a source file which would occur earlier than `Entity` when sorted alphabetically (as this seems to be VC++'s way of choosing link order), it fails, but if I place this implementation in a file which is linked *after*, it works as intended. I still am not sure how to make it work universally though.

Comment: I also have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed out in your Edit, the problem lies in the order of initialization, i.e. what happens before the main method is invoked.

In the same file (compilation unit to be precise) you can rely on the order of execution of constructors for static objects to match the order they appear in your source code.

When your program is made by multiple compilation units, the order in which compilation units are constructed is up to the implementation.

There's a way to achieve your goal since the compiler first initializes all static storage and then invokes static object constructors - you need to make sure that every time you access `static std::map<std::string, TCreateMethod> s_methods;` it is properly initialized. You can achieve this by declaring it static within a method. E.g.:

```cpp
static std::map<std::string, TCreateMethod>& methods()
{
    static std::map<std::string, TCreateMethod> singleton;
    return singleton;
}
```

This ensures that the first time this function is called, the map object (named singleton) is constructed and it is returned.

This technique, sometimes referred to as *Meyer's Singleton* is called lazy evaluation, meaning that required operations are delayed up to the last minute just before they are needed.

(I found a great and detailed explanation about C++ static initialization here: https://pabloariasal.github.io/2020/01/02/static-variable-initialization/)